# intersection of dates for an arbitrary number of time series in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, time-series

How do I calculate the intersection of dates for an arbitrary number of time series in SQL without loops?

Given that I have a table with 3 columns

1. GroupId
2. Start Date
3. End Date

for each GroupId there are multiple rows - so multiple start/end dates per GroupId (within a group there is no overlapping)

What I would like to do is find all the intersecting dates between all the groups
So if Group 1 has the following dates

```
1/1/2001 - 1/31/2001
3/31/2001 - 4/5/2001
```

Group 2 has the following

```
1/25/2001 - 5/1/2001
```

Group 3 has the following

```
1/22/2001 - 4/1/2001
```

The above all intersect at:

```
1/25/2001 - 1/31/2001
3/31/2001 - 1/4/2001
```

How do I do this in SQL? The following has the logic for 2 date ranges within one table, but I need it for n date ranges in one table:

```
SELECT 
    case 
        when t1.StartDate > t2.StartDate then t1.StartDate 
        else t2.StartDate 
    END as StartDate,
    CASE WHEN t1.EndDate < t2.EndDate THEN t1.EndDate
        ELSE t2.EndDate
    END as EndDate
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.StartDate <= t2.EndDate AND t1.EndDate >= t2.StartDate
```

(note: As an additional constraint I am doing this in linq to sql)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by separating out the dates in the groups and using cumulative sums and then some comparisons.  In SQL Server 2012+, this looks like:

```
with g as (
      select groupid, start as dte, 1 as enters, 0 as exits
      from t
      union all
      select groupid, dateadd(day, 1, end), 0, 1
      from t
     ),
     gs as (
      select groupid, dte, sum(enters) as enters, sum(exits) as exits,
             sum(sum(enters)) over (order by dte) as cumeenters,
             sum(sum(exits)) over (order by dte) as cumexits
      from g
      group by dte, groupid
     )
select ne, nextdte
from (select gs.*, lead(dte) over (order by dte) as nextdte
      from gs
     ) gs
where cumeenters - cumeexits = (select count(distinct groupid) from t);
```

The processing is as follows:

- The first subquery separates the start and end dates into separate records.
- The second accumulates the starts and the ends to get the cumulative values.
- The `where` clause chooses the dates where all the groups are represented.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33f6a/13) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: there are 3 distinct groupids. groupid 1 has 2 rows, groupid 2 and 2 have 1 row each, multiply by 2 (for 1 rows as start, 1 row as end) = 4 rows, 2 rows and 2 rows respectively (in cte `g`').  how can groups with only 2 rows reach a cumulative of 3? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33f6a/5

Comment: remove `partition by ` for cumenters & cumexists see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/515cd/1

Comment: wow - thank you very much - its going to take me a couple of days just to convert this to linq